# Calculating power measurement error from V and I error margins

Tags: power, dc, accuracy, power-measurement

I am using a [Yokogawa WT310](http://tmi.yokogawa.com/us/products/digital-power-analyzers/digital-power-analyzers/digital-power-meter-wt300e/) for measuring DC power.  The manual ([available here](https://y-link.yokogawa.com/YL022/)) says that both current and voltage have accuracy of +/-(0.1% of reading + 0.2% of range).

Assume this example setup:

> Input current: 700mA
>   Current Range: 1A
>   Input voltage: 10v
>   Voltage Range: 15v

Based on that setup and the meter specifications, we can calculate the following:

> P = V * I = 7w
>   V<sub>error</sub> = +/-(0.001 * 10v + 0.002 * 15v) = +/- 0.04v
>   I<sub>error</sub> = +/-(0.001 * 0.7A + 0.002 * 1A) = +/- 0.0027A

My goal is to calculate the power measurement's error margin. Here's what I've done:

> P<sub>error</sub> = V<sub>error</sub> * I<sub>error</sub> = 0.04v * 0.0027A = 0.000108w

Note that in this example, P<sub>error</sub> is **less than** both V<sub>error</sub> and I<sub>error</sub>.

Now imagine I'm using a less accurate meter and measuring much higher voltage and current ranges. Assume I get these results for error margins:

> V<sub>error</sub> = 1.17v
>   I<sub>error</sub> = 1.2A
>   P<sub>error</sub> = V<sub>error</sub> * I<sub>error</sub> = 1.17v * 1.2A = 1.404w

Now, P<sub>error</sub> is **greater than** both V<sub>error</sub> and I<sub>error</sub>.

This makes sense mathematically; that's just how multiplying numbers less than 1 and greater than 1 works. But it makes me feel like I'm missing something conceptually. Shouldn't P<sub>error</sub> scale consistently relative to V<sub>error</sub> and I<sub>error</sub>? Am I just calculating P<sub>error</sub> incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh yes, you're definitely missing something. You can't focus on the errors without looking at the "non-errors". Let's use your second example, where you got a power error of 1.404 watts. What is the "non-error" component?

Just for grins, assume that the real voltage was 100 volts and the real current 20 amps. Then the real power was 2,000 W, but the inaccurate readings were 101.17 volts and 21.2 A, for an incorrect power calculation of 2144.8 watts, or a power error of 144.8 watts.

If you consider each measurement as a base plus an error, and the errors are normalized with respect to the base (such as you would do with percentage errors) then $$(1 + x)(1 + y) = 1 + x + y + xy$$ and the error term is the sum of the errors plus their product. For small errors the product term is negligible, and the error is simply the sum of the errors.

For non-normalized errors, as in your example, you need to compute $$P = (V + {\delta}v)(i+{\delta}i) = Vi + V{\delta}i + i{\delta}V +{\delta}V{\delta}i $$ and the power error E is simply $$E = V{\delta}i + i{\delta}V +{\delta}V{\delta}i $$

So, yes, your reservations were correct.

[image]

*Figure 1. A graphical representation of the \$VI\$ term (green), \$V \delta i \$ term (red), \$ i \delta V \$, term (blue) and \$ \delta V \delta i \$ term (white). It can be seen that, in this case, the \$ \delta V \delta i \$  term contributes very little to the overall error and that about 80% of the error is due to the \$V \delta i \$ term.*

Comment: You've made me think about this a little. I've taken the liberty of adding Figure 1 and its caption. Please feel free to delete / edit as you see fit or if I've totally missed your point.

Comment: @Transistor Your picture caption says "cut... V and I scales are identical as is required to make the areas meaningful".I really cannot follow you, could you clarify?

Comment: @carloc - If Transistor had used a square rather than a proportional rectangle, it would be impossible to see that the V term is much larger than the i term (for the specific V and i which were used here).

Comment: I think @carloc is right. I was thinking that different scaling might make \$ V \delta i \$ look more significant than \$ I \delta V \$ but it doesn't - they'll all scale the same amount. All the areas will still be proportional so if we divide the volts scale by two all the areas become VA/2. I'll remove the sentence.

Comment: Yes your quite right, any "power rectangle" is scaled just the same, so you do not loose their areas ratio. BTW one might also think that current and voltage scales are dimensional quantities, say they are A/mm and V/mm, so again they can't be compared.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you are asking the question. For Yokogawa Power meters and analysers the accuracy for the power measurement is fully specified, including that for DC, so it is unnecessary to use the accuracy of the voltage and current measurements to derive the power accuracy. Using a formula is almost certain to produce a poorer specfication.

Please see the relevant specifications in the brochure for the WT300E at the top of page 12:

https://www.yokogawa.com/pdf/provide/E/GW/Bulletin/0000029826/0/BUWT300E-01EN.pdf

A power range is the multiple of the voltage and current ranges. In a Yokogawa power meter, these are rms ranges, not peak, so the actual power error due to the range error can be typically three times less than that for power meters that specify using peak ranges for voltage and current. This is of course is more relevant for AC waveforms than DC.

Comment: That specification shows two configurations: "WT310E/WT310EH/
WT332E/WT333E (Current EXT sensor input)" and "WT310EH (Current Direct input)". My meter is a WT310-D-C2, which I suppose fits in the first column model names (it would be nice if the exact model name in the manual, "WT310E", matched what's printed on the meter label, "WT310"). But I'm not using an external sensor, so I can't use those numbers. I don't have a WT310EH, so I can't use the second column either. Where is the **direct input** for a **WT310E** specified?

Answer (score -1):

Consideration on difference between absolute and relative errors are quite correct.

But I belive what should be clearly pointed out about @skrrgwasme concerns is that is **totally, absolutely, hopelessly  meaningless to compare different quantities**.

There is no chance to say wether 1 volt is more or less than 1 ampere, and so with watt or anything not equivalent to volt.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @skrrgwasme call it comment, hint, advice, suggestion, tip or whatever you like but please do not miss what it means.